# 2D plot marker color cannot be changed after color assignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, mark

I have the following MWE for producing the plot. It can be observed for the plot "path2" that the ball color remains blue (has to be red), even though mark color "red" was assigned.
So, i need to change ball color for ''path2" plotted in red line.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=Distance from center, ylabel=Appointment,xlabel={Follow-ups},
            xlabel style={yshift=-5mm},
            xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
            xticklabels = {
                \strut A1,
                \strut A2,
                \strut A3,
                \strut A4,
                \strut A5,
                \strut A6,
                \strut A7,
                \strut A8,
                \strut A9,
                \strut A10
            },
            x tick label style={text width=5em,anchor=north,align=center}, 
            ymin=0,
            ymax=20,
            grid style=dashed, 
            legend style={
                at={(0.738,0.8209)},
                anchor=south west,
            },]
            \addplot[color=blue, mark=ball, mark color=blue] coordinates{(1,6.5)(2,11)(3,17.4)(4,11)(5,17.4)(6,6.5)(7,17.4)(8,6.5)(9,11)(10,11)};
        \addplot[color=red, mark=ball, mark color=red]  coordinates{(1,5.9)(2,9.5)(3,13.4)(4,8.5)(5,13.7)(6,6)(7,14.3)(8,5.3)(9,9.2)(10,9.4)};
            \legend{path, path2}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=Distance from center, ylabel=Appointment,xlabel={Follow-ups},
            xlabel style={yshift=-5mm},
            xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
            xticklabels = {
                \strut A1,
                \strut A2,
                \strut A3,
                \strut A4,
                \strut A5,
                \strut A6,
                \strut A7,
                \strut A8,
                \strut A9,
                \strut A10
            },
            x tick label style={text width=5em,anchor=north,align=center}, 
            ymin=0,
            ymax=20,
            grid style=dashed, 
            legend style={
,                at={(0.738,0.8209)},
                anchor=south west,
            },]
          \addplot[color=blue, mark=ball, mark color=blue] coordinates{(1,6.5)(2,11)(3,17.4)(4,11)(5,17.4)(6,6.5)(7,17.4)(8,6.5)(9,11)(10,11)};
        \addplot[red,mark=ball,mark options={ball color=red}]  coordinates{(1,5.9)(2,9.5)(3,13.4)(4,8.5)(5,13.7)(6,6)(7,14.3)(8,5.3)(9,9.2)(10,9.4)};
            \legend{path, path2}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear vi pa, thank you very much